# How can I make checkbox enabled/disabled after trigger check or uncheck event in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I was wrote a custom template for checkbox control that it display green for checked and display red for unchecked.I want to the checkbox control make itself disabled for 3 seconds after trigger check/uncheck event and then recover itself enabled.How can I integrate the function to my custom template?

```
<Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid1">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid x:Name="grid">
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Stroke="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="22">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,0" StartPoint="0.5,1">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF86CC6E" Offset="0.022"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF47E211" Offset="0.81"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Arial Black" FontSize="10.667" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Content=""/>
                    <Grid x:Name="grid1">
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Stroke="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="22">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,0" StartPoint="0.5,1">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFDE6666" Offset="0.022"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFB2611" Offset="0.81"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Arial Black" FontSize="10.667" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: you want it in xaml or code-behind?

Comment: whether xaml or code-behind that is ok

Answer (score 2):

There is at least a way using `Trigger` like this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
      <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="ffIsEnabled" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled">
           <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled">
               <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False"/>
               <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="True"/>
           </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
      </ControlTemplate.Resources>
      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
               <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ffIsEnabled}"/>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
               <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ffIsEnabled}"/>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
         </Trigger>
      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <!-- ... -->
</ControlTemplate>
```